# Didn't getting any response while fetching Ethereum event logs data (of specific event) using Nethereum in C# console application

Tags: c#

I am working in C# console application and need to read Ethereum event logs of specific event from Ethereum API. I have preferred Nethereum to do that task. But, Whenever i try to fetch the Event logs using API call then nothing is getting as output. Didn't get any expected data.

I have a following parameters to get event logs:

1. Ethereum API url
2. Contract ABI address
3. Contract address
4. Event name

following are the lines of code, which i am using to get event logs using Nethereum library in C# console application:

```
var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3(@UrlString);
var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(@abi, @contractAddress);
var event = contract.GetEvent(@eventName);
var filter = await event.CreateFilterAsync();
var logs = await event.GetAllChanges<MultipliedEvent>(filter);
```

Didn't getting in "logs". Is anything missing by me?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to create a filterinput from all blocks? Like this?

```cs
var _firstBlock = BlockParameter.CreateEarliest();
var _lastBlock = BlockParameter.CreateLatest();
var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3(@UrlString);
var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(@abi, @contractAddress);
var @event = contract.GetEvent(@eventName);
var filterInput = @event.CreateFilterInput(_firstBlock, _lastBlock);
var logs = await @event.GetAllChanges<MultipliedEvent>(filterInput);
```